# Try to learn how to evaluate and convert an unsigned int to a boolean state

Tags: int, boolean

My overall project is to use an Arduino Mega to control a Maxx7219 to address a matrix of 64 individual LEDs, with data being imported from an outside source (DCSBios) formatted as an unsigned int. The 7219 provides me with the ability to address up to 64 individual LEDs. In my project I am using preexisting provided code that receives data from a separate program as an unsigned int and I need to evaluate/convert that value to a useable Boolean state value to activate a specific led on 7219 led matrix. I have studied and believe I understand how to set up the 7219 for use and have found the command to address the specific address, row and column, I am stuck on how to use and convert the int data into the useable Boolean state for this purpose. The example provided below is just one of 56 separate but identically formatted queries that I am seeking to send to the matrix from my completed sketch. It is my hope that someone can help me to understand how this is accomplished so I can implement the solution for the additional LEDs. Thanks for taking the time to look and thanks in advance if you can assist in this endeavor.

Provided code; 0 = off, 1 = on

void onMasterCautionLtChange(unsigned int newValue) {

```
   /* your code here */
```

}

DcsBios::IntegerBuffer masterCautionLtBuffer(0x7408, 0x0200, 9, onMasterCautionLtChange);

the output statement to address the specific LED matrix point, from the reference documents; false = off, true = on

/* Set the status of a single Led.

- Params :
- addr  address of the display
- row   the row of the Led (0..7)
- col   the column of the Led (0..7)
- state If true the led is switched on, if false it is switched off

*/

void setLed(int addr, int row, int col, boolean state);

Answer (score 0):

I would just write a simple function

```
bool intToBool(int input) {
    return input > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It has provided the result I was after.